# Reusing unfolding/multipart beamer slides

Tags: beamer

In an incredibly short amount of time, I have amassed quite a few slides, i.e. beamer frames, where I step through procedures, architectures, roadmaps and such.

These frames include a lot of `\only` and `\visible` blocks and are generally decorated with `<...>` all over. I am now looking for a way to reuse these frames, but not entirely, just a few select views. With this I would like to be able to step through the frame more quickly. For instance, when it takes me 10 clicks to step through a procedure during a workshop, I would like to move through the same procedure in just four steps during the final presentation. I always have these things as just one frame, that adds or removes bits and pieces to itself.

Currently I copy/paste the frame and then adjust all the `<...>` parameters to fit my needs. This is tedious work and not rewarding at all. What I would like to do is copy/paste the frame and then tell (Lua)LaTeX: "just give me the views 1, 4, 8 and 10". Or maybe simply: "give me view 5".

Does this exist in ready-to-use already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `\againframe` to select which ever overlays you want to repeat later on.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
    abc
    \pause
    efg
    \pause
    hij
\end{frame} 

\againframe<1,3>{foo}

\end{document}
```